# BeautifulSoup >> IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am performing a simple web-scraping with below Python function that uses BeautifulSoup.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def webcheck(company,cat,count):
  query = '%s +%s' %(company,cat)
  url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q='+query

  headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0'}
  source = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text 

  # BeautifulSoup
  soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
  search_div = soup.find_all(class_='rc')
  return [search_div[x].find(class_='st').text for x in range(count)]

company, cat, count = ('Walmart','+stock quote', 3)
webcheck(company,cat,count)
```

It works and returns top 3 lines of text from the search as intended.

It further works on a `DataFrame` of 5 rows (using `apply(lambda x: webcheck(x.name,key,3), axis=1)`.

But not in a larger `DataFrame` of 2000 rows, which produces below error.

```
 IndexError: list index out of range
```

Strange and the most confusing thing is that both single search (using the function) or search in the same DataFrame of 5 rows afterward also stop working....until the few hours or next day.

Grateful for any insights or solutions.

Comment: Please provide the entire error output, as well as a [mcve].

Comment: Google doesn't like scraping. If you put in a try/except block around your list comprehension in the webcheck function and print the data you get on an exception you'll probably see a captcha or something similar.